# Pause on hover in jquery

Tags: jquery, hover, slider, gallery

I have a carousel on my website. http://blog.vishopper.com/ I have changed it to go to a specific slide after 1 second of .mouseover on the corresponding tab.

Now I want the slider to pause on that specific slide, not continue cycling through.

here is the code for the slider.

```
if($('#zSlider').length != 0){

  $('#zSlider').carousel({interval: parseInt(zAlive_i18n.slider_pause_time) }).bind('slid',function(){

    $('#zSlider .description li.active').removeClass('active');

    $('#zSlider .description li:eq(' + $('#zSlider .carousel-inner .active').index('#zSlider .carousel-inner .item') + ')').addClass('active');

  });

  $('#zSlider .description li').mouseover(function(){
  var me = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#zSlider').carousel($(me).index('#zSlider .description li'));
  }, 1000);
  });

  $('#zSlider .description li').hover(

    function(){$(this).addClass('over')},

    function(){$(this).removeClass('over')}

  );

}
```

There is other stuff wrong with it but i'll try to get this sorted first. Pausing was the default behavior but it seems to have broke.

Answer (score 0):

On mouse hover have it clearInterval(foo) and when you mouse out, it resets the interval. It seems as though you might be using a plugin? Which makes it harder to control the interval set by it. That's the general idea though.